# Mapper fails to locate foreign keys on secondary table (Many to many relationship)

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to describe a simple  "many to many" relationship using flask-SQLAlchemy, however, the mapper does'nt seem to find the foreign keys on my secondary table, even though they are correctly defined.

I'm using the latest version os flask-SQLAlchemy (2.4) and SQLite. I've tried many code variations and still, nothing. Doumentation is not helping either =/

```py
user_permit = db.table('userpermit',
    db.Column('permit_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('permit.permit_id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('user_mail', db.String(128), db.ForeignKey('user.user_mail'), primary_key=True)
)

class User(db.Model):
    user_mail = db.Column(db.String(128), primary_key=True)

[...]
    permits = db.relationship('Permit', secondary=user_permit, backref='users_permitted')

class Permit(db.Model):
    permit_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

I always get the same error message: NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.permits - there are no foreign keys linking these tables via secondary table ''.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify 'primaryjoin' and 'secondaryjoin' expressions.

It seems it does not recognize my secondary table, since it says '', instead of 'userpermit'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because you're defining `db.table`, not `db.Table`. Otherwise, a few other things to check:

- Because you're not specifying `__tablename__ =` for each table, check the names of the tables are what you're expecting, e.g. `permit` & `user`.
- You can manually specify the join condition using the [`primaryjoin`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions) parameter of `relationship()`, which allows you to provide the SQL to determine the join

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly it. It should have been db.Table (capital "T"). Too much time looking at the screen =D

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you guys. Too much time looking at the code lines. Turns out I was instantiating db.table('user permit'..... instead of db.Table (with capital T)

Thank you.